# Getting a custom value from the wordpress database

Tags: php, wordpress

A co-developer created a custom form in the admin section of the Wordpress admin area. I am trying to get the value to show it elsewhere on the admin section. I thought get_option() would allow me to get that value by calling it by the name, but its not returning the value and I have no idea how to call.

Here is the sections he created, so I thought I could get it using get_option('contact_person_address').

```
$wp_customize->add_control( new WP_Customize_Control( $wp_customize, 'contact_person_address', array(
            'label'        => __( 'Site Contact Room Number &amp; Building', 'coe' ),
            'section'    => 'contact_person',
            'settings'   => 'contact_person_address',
        ) ) );
```

and

```
$wp_customize->add_setting( 'contact_person_address' , array(
                'default'     => '',
                'transport'   => 'postMessage',
            ) );
```

It just returns the default I assign to the function.

Comment: Surely you want [get_setting()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Customize_Manager/get_setting) rather than get_option()

Comment: The get_setting() function is depreciated and they suggest using get_option() http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_settings

Comment: Here is the answer:  get_theme_mod()

Comment: Please note that `$wp_customize->get_setting()` which I referenced is not the same as the deprecated core wp function get_settings()

Answer (score 0):

You use  get_theme_mod() to get the value of the custom field